# .NET Remoting memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I have a Remoting Class as a Singleton

```
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <service>
            <wellknown 
               mode="Singleton" 
               type="PTSSLinkClasses.PTSSLinkClientDesktopRemotable, PTSSLinkClasses" 
               objectUri="PTSSLinkDesktop" />
         </service>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="http" port="8901"/>
         </channels>
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Its created within a "server" Service.
Another client service consumes this remote object.
The client is calling the remote object every .5 second using a timer (polling) (for testing)

If the server service is stopped, so the remote object is not available, memory useage for the client service keeps increasing......

I have overwritten InitialLifetimeService to return a null

```
public override Object InitializeLifetimeService()
        {
            return null;
        }
```

If a remote object is not available does .net queue all the call requests to this object??? untill all the memory is consumed?
How can I dected if the remote object is not available and stop trying to call the remote method?

Answer (score 3):

.NET Remoting doesn´t queue the calls to remote objects. When a remote object is no longer available and you call a method on it, you should receive an Exception (WebException, RemotingException), that the requested service is not found.

I think your problem is somewhere else. Maybe you ignore the possible Exception in your code and doesn´t handle it corretly.

Do you use the same timer again for calling the remote object, or do you create every .5 seconds a new timer to call the remote object?

Comment: Also, don't be fooled by how you're measuring memory and by how the garbage collection works in .NET. It may simply be that no garbage collection happened or had anything to collect. Memory leaks can have all kinds of sources, I strongly suggest reading up on .NET memory and garbage collection.